# PHP - set all empty or null in an array, to 0, without a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm working with a large array. We're displaying all fields of data in the array with a table. Some fields in the array are null because the user hasn't accumulated anything in that field. However, we wanted a zero for when they have such a result. Our solution was to display the value along with intval()

`intval(@$users[$user_id]['loggedin_time'])`

Which is fine, but it is ugly and inelegant. Is there a way, without a foreach loop, to set all values of '' in the array to be 0?

Comment: What is the default value? Can you just set that to 0 when you create the array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$input = array(...);
$output = array_map(function($item) { return $item ?: 0; }, $input);
```

The above example uses facilities of PHP >= 5.3 (inline anonymous function declaration and the short form of the ternary operator), but you can do the same in any PHP version (only perhaps more verbosely).

You should think a bit about the conditional inside the callback function; the one I 'm using here will replace all values that evaluate to `false` as booleans with zeroes (this does include the empty string, but it also includes e.g. `null` values -- so you might want to tweak the condition, depending on your needs).

**Update: PHP < 5.3 version**

It's either this:

```
function callback($item) {
    return $item == false ? 0 : $item;
}

$output = array_map('callback', $input);
```

Or this:

```
$output = array_map(
     create_function('$item', 'return $item == false ? 0 : $item;'),
     $input);
```

Comment: Just to be pedantic - this'll still use a loop. It'll just be done invisibly inside PHP instead of explicitly via foreach() or whatever.

Comment: You need to be checking for `$item['loggedin_time']`.

Comment: @MarcB: Obviously, but this question strikes me as one with practical applications (keep it short), not theoretical (can this be done without a loop).

Comment: @konforce: Why? `$input` would be `$users[$user_id]`.

Comment: @Jon, I assumed he wants to do so for the entire array `$users` array upfront, but as he's already iterating over that somehow, he might as well just call `array_map` once per iteration (per your solution).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are retrieving this information from a database of some sort.

If you are getting the array from a Mysql Table try something like this:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,36579,36579#msg-36579